# Convert String to PDF

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, pdf, spring-restcontroller

I have String which is converted from PDF using `EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity())`. How can I convert the above string back to PDF using Java API in the Spring boot controller?
below is the String which I got after conversion of pdf to String.

```
%PDF-1.4
%áâãä 
1 0 obj
<<
/R8 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
[ /Indexed /DeviceRGB 255
<000000FFFFFFBC9B6ABC9B6ABC9B6ABC9B6ABC9B6ABC9B6AFFFFFFBC9B6AFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>
]
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/R7 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/OPM 1>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/R9 6 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Subtype /Image
/ColorSpace 2 0 R
/Width 201
/Height 201
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 1935>>
stream
xœí›Ù’ä(E#¼ãÿÿØ±‘`§]Ý1=£óTtÙdU)Š¢(Š¢(Š¢(Š¢(Š¢(Š¢(Š¢(Š¢(Š¢(Š¢(Š¢(Š¢(-õAó8uÛ  êªêeHWåA7´iŽ>ìºÀ4F3v^Î€µœŽÉž‡ÙV†LUtCæèÃ®L£A†    Lï¿ÊÓýÛ…ŒYkþF!3Yt»m¿œÐt˜ÐµiÐ–U“ó¹õiÖK=ŒŽµT©]q´6wÑµŒjz“–vÉ
    wm0gù/\•Ìz1<¿˜uŒ.ÅAÑ=·Ï=B]‡MPç†¥ñ4òBõÓdZË,¯J¼ÝJ-î¡lMÖ**
```

Comment: That String **is a** pdf. That is just the content of the PDF file, if you write it to disk it is still a pdf. So not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @M.Deinum   Actually Pdf is converted to String by using existing api EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()) . I am again want to convert it to PDF .

Comment: A PDF is **not** a string, it's binary content. Never try to convert it to a string.

Comment: @Olivier . our internal API convert pdf to String using EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()) . How can we convert back to Pdf

Comment: Fix your internal API so that it doesn't call `EntityUtils.toString()` on a PDF.

Comment: For some backgrounds - PDF is a binary format (even though a number of its elements are defined in terms of ASCII strings and lines), and handling binary data as strings can change the data beyond repair.

Comment: @mkl  now I am trying to convert PDF from Httpresponse to Entityresponse but I am not able convert that pdf . Even after download I found pdf is empty